# Setting a value using jQuery to post JSON to an ASP.Net Web API 2 service

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-web-api2

I have a seemingly simple jQuery ajax function to post an array of integers to a web service:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#testButton").click(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "api/setactivedemodatasetids/",
            data: [1, 2, 8, 9],
            success: function() {},
            dataType: "application/json"
        });
    });
});
```

And a simple ASP.Net Web API 2 controller to receive the posted data:

```
[Route("api/setactivedemodatasetids/")]
[AcceptVerbs("POST")]
public void SetActiveDemoDataSetIds(int[] ids)
{
    var db = new DataClassesDataContext();
    // Do stuff
    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

When I set a breakpoint in the controller the value of the parameter `ids` is

```
{int[0]}
```

Why? Why isn't it an array of four integers 1, 2, 8, and 9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set `dataType: "json"` set `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8"` and data: `JSON.stringify([1, 2, 8, 9] )`

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

I think this code will solve your problem

```
$("#testButton").click(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                        dataType: "json",
                        url: "api/setactivedemodatasetids/",
                        data: JSON.stringify([1, 2, 8, 9]),
                        success: function () { },
                        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(xhr.status);
                            //alert(xhr.responseText);
                            alert(thrownError);
                        }

                    });
                });
```

Comment: That's changed the value of `ids` I see at the breakpoint in the controller from `{int[0]}` to `null`, not the array of integers I was hoping for. But thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Bingo! I've got it, I'll edit your answer and accept it. The data should be `JSON.stringify([1, 2, 8, 9])`

Comment: It looks like the `dataType: "json"` and the `charset=utf-8` are optional as your solution works in both IE and Chrome without those fragments